# SSL certificate with common name as ip address

Tags: networking, dns, ssl, certificate, iot

I'm trying to encrypt data between IoT devices and my server, so I'm using self-signed certificates (currently using OpenSSL). Now I've run into the issue where a common name in the certificate needs to be a fully qualified domain name (FQDN), but I manage my domain on Cloudflare and it does not allow me to route TCP traffic via their proxy (free plan).

What I can do now is point the traffic directly via IP of the server and add the common name (CN) in the certificate as the IP of the server. The problem with this is:

- Maintaining the certificates for all the servers because the server IP's may change
- I don't think adding IP as FQDN is a good practice

What can I do to route the traffic via DNS, since Cloudflare does not let me proxy TCP requests through them?

Also, what can go wrong with the above setup if I use a hierarchical PKI maintained on my own?

Also if there is anything wrong in the current setup, please let me know.

Comment: I don't really understand where the problem is. What's wrong with adding the server's name to Cloudflare?  (I mean, if you point traffic directly to the server's IP address, then the server's IP address is _also_ exposed and no DoS protection, isn't it?)

Comment: yes, I agree with that. So, if I go ahead with the Cloudflare setup and use self-signed certificates and use a hierarchical PKI for this, can something go wrong?

Comment: You mean the combination of Cloudflare DNS but custom PKI?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot, Cloudflare currently does not allow TCP requests to be proxied via them.

Comment: @grawity yes that, but sorry for my continuous edits, but yea Cloudflare does not allow TCP requests to be proxied through them